# How to change currency in magento soap api

Tags: api, soap, currency, web-services, currency-rates

I am using Magento 1.8.1 and SOAP API 2. I couldn't find a way to change the currency for the API. How can I do this ? Or is this not possible with Magento ?

And if this is not possible, is there a way to extract currency values(values coming from the webservicex) in Magento ?

Comment: are you want to change currency rate?

Comment: I want to change the currency of retrieving products and detail product etc. It is better if there is a way to get currency rates or change currency without extending all related API calls

Comment: @AmitBera Not the rates. Currency itself. Currently all products listing with base currency USD. and i want to change it with a param or something. (not to change the base currency)

Comment: @user3932169 can you please share your solution? I have 2 websites in 2 different currencies. the price doesn't automatically converted as per the rate set in Ststem > Manage Currency > Rates

Answer (score -2):

```
public function getCurrency() {
        $CurrencyCode = Mage::getModel('core/config_data')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('path','currency/options/allow')
                        ->getData();
        $currencies_array = explode(',',$CurrencyCode[0]['value']);
        if($currencies_array[0] == ''){
            $currencies_array[]= Mage::app()->getStore($site_id)->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
        }
        return $currencies_array;
    }
```

---

This function will return all the currency codes for different websites. If you want Currency for a particular Website, or Store_view, you need to add filter with that.